# Internet Explorer forces displaced positioning

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, jquery-masonry, absolute

**Hi guys,**

I've created a reference page for a client with a mosaic of a lot of houses. Everything aligns and works fine in every browser, but Internet Explorer is making problems as usual.

Usually in other browsers every picture is in line and we've got nice rows. But in IE 9-11 something seems to bee displaced (lower versions not supported):

> **IMAGE:** http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2014-09k5ke1.png

Each `.gallery-item` gets individual inline attributes from  either the script "Masonry" or Wordpress (I'm not quite sure).

```
element.style {
  position: absolute;
  left: 419px; /* varies with each gallery-item */
  top: 1400px; /* varies with each gallery-item */
}
```

The styles for `.gallery-item` are:

```
#gallery-1 .gallery-item {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 12%;
}

.gallery-item {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0px !important;
  width: 12% !important;
}
```

### For more info please visit this [Live-Link](http://www.kosima-haus.de/referenzen/).

Where could the fix for IE be?

Thank you all in advance for your help and consideration.

Comment: Do you use a CSS reset stylesheet? Sometimes IE renders margins, etc., slightly differently than other browsers.

Comment: Also, have you noticed how the order of the houses in IE are different than that of other browsers? It seems in IE some of the `dl`s representing a house of the very left columns are jumping to the very right.

Comment: Instead of absolute positioning try display: inline-block.